# can we have multiple xsl:templates with match="/"?

Tags: xml, xslt

Can we have multiple xsl:templates with match="/" and different name. Basically I want to iterate an xml till some levels and then start iterating again from "/" if some condition is met. So I am thinking of making a `<xsl:call-template name="option-1">` or `<xsl:call-template name="option-1">` based on some conditions where both option-1 and option-2 will be like `<xsl:template match="/" name="option-1">` and `<xsl:template match="/" name="option-2">` respectively.

If there is a better way, I am open. All I want is to start iterating from root node again.

Answer (score 4):

The concept you're looking for is template *modes*.  You can define

```
<xsl:template match="/" mode="option1">
```

and likewise `option2`, and your initial starting template with no mode

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="some-condition">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="option1" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise test="some-condition">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="option2" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

[XSLT 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes), [XSLT 2.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes)

Comment: So I can have both the starting template and these condition based templates with match="/" that can iterate from the beginning (root) again even when one is called from inside of other where I am already a few levels looped down?

Comment: or in other words - does select="/" helps iterating from root and not the current node from where apply-template is called ?

Comment: Although this would work, it would be more XSLT-like to just define the template as `<xsl:template match="/[some-condition]">`, and then define another one with another condition. Of course, depending on the subsequent processing of descendant nodes, modes still could be useful. The other thought that occurs to me is, are you sure you don't want two different XSLT programs and just invoke the one you want?

Comment: @user1314871 yes, `select="/"` selects the root document node regardless of which node is the current context.